# Validate XML File with the XSD and write the name of the differences in a text file Using Java or any Programming Language

Tags: java, python, xml, xsd, difference

Is there any way to compare my XML with the XSD by using Java/Python and write those element names in a text file which are not in synch with the schema.

Answer (score 0):

The Saxon schema validator has an option to produce an XML report of the invalidities found. You can then write an XSLT transformation to format this report any way you like. Here is an example of the report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-report xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/validation"
                   system-id="file:/Users/mike/repo2/samples/data/books-invalid.xml">
   <error line="3"
          column="17"
          path="/Q{}BOOKLIST[1]/Q{}BOOKS[1]/@x"
          xsd-part="1"
          constraint="cvc-complex-type.3">Attribute @x is not allowed on element &lt;BOOKS&gt;</error>
   <error line="10"
          column="17"
          path="/Q{}BOOKLIST[1]/Q{}BOOKS[1]/Q{}ITEM[1]/Q{}PRICE[1]"
          xsd-part="2"
          constraint="cvc-datatype-valid.1">The content "$0.2" of element &lt;PRICE&gt; does not match the required simple type. Cannot convert string to decimal: $0.2</error>
   <error line="21"
          column="20"
          path="/Q{}BOOKLIST[1]/Q{}BOOKS[1]/Q{}ITEM[2]/Q{}PUB-DATE[1]"
          xsd-part="2"
          constraint="cvc-datatype-valid.1">The content "2002-02-31" of element &lt;PUB-DATE&gt; does not match the required simple type. Invalid date "2002-02-31" (Non-existent date)</error>
   <error line="42"
          column="22"
          path="/Q{}BOOKLIST[1]/Q{}BOOKS[1]/Q{}ITEM[3]/Q{}REPUTATION[1]"
          xsd-part="1"
          constraint="cvc-complex-type.2.4">In content of element &lt;ITEM&gt;: The content model does not allow element &lt;REPUTATION&gt; to appear immediately after element &lt;WEIGHT&gt;. No further elements are allowed at this point. </error>
   <meta-data>
      <validator name="SAXON-EE" version="9.8.0.9"/>
      <results errors="4" warnings="0"/>
      <schema file="books.xsd" xsd-version="1.1"/>
      <run at="2018-03-07T15:22:04.847Z"/>
   </meta-data>
</validation-report>
```

Comment: Hello Michael Kay, Can I used this package of Saxon in Java and can we write those elements in a text file using XSLT transformation?

Comment: Yes and Yes. Full information in the Saxon documentation at www.saxonica.com